# Salesforce Org (Identity Provider) to Salesforce Org (Service Provider) Single Sign On

Tags: single-sign-on, identity

Where can I find updated instructions to configure Salesforce Org (Identity Provider) to Salesforce Org (Service Provider) Single Sign On?

I'd settle for a Federation Id match, but I'd love to be able to match on email address if possible.

Comment: How about the [Environment Hub](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=environment_hub_main.htm)?